# Как правильно отправить запрос через SOAP?

Tags: php, soap

есть некий XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header/>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <OperationHistoryRequest xmlns="****">
           <Barcode>11773847072818</Barcode>
           <MessageType>0</MessageType>
       </OperationHistoryRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

есть адрес

http://*****.ru:8080/niips-operationhistory-web/OperationHistory?wsdl
по данному URL можно получить такой ответ, просто набрав его в URL

```
<!--
Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.3.3-hudson-757-SNAPSHOT.
-->
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory" xmlns:msg="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="OperationHistory" targetNamespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://vpdks1.russianpost.ru:8080/niips-operationhistory-web/OperationHistory?xsd=1" namespace="http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getOperationHistoryIn">
<part name="historyRequest" element="msg:OperationHistoryRequest"/>
<part name="AuthorizationHeader" element="msg:AuthorizationHeader"/>
</message>
<message name="getOperationHistoryOut">
<part name="messagePart" element="msg:OperationHistoryData"/>
</message>
<message name="AuthorizationFault">
<part name="Reason" element="msg:AuthorizationFaultReason"/>
</message>
<message name="OperationHistoryFault">
<part name="Reason" element="msg:OperationHistoryFaultReason"/>
</message>
<message name="UpdateOperationDataRequest">
<part name="UpdateRequest" element="msg:UpdateOperationRequest"/>
<part name="AuthorizationHeader" element="msg:AuthorizationHeader"/>
</message>
<message name="UpdateOperationDataResponse">
<part name="messagePart" element="msg:OperationHistoryData"/>
</message>
<portType name="OperationHistoryInterface">
<operation name="GetOperationHistory">
<input message="tns:getOperationHistoryIn"/>
<output message="tns:getOperationHistoryOut"/>
<fault name="AuthorizationFault" message="tns:AuthorizationFault"/>
<fault name="OperationHistoryFault" message="tns:OperationHistoryFault"/>
</operation>
<operation name="UpdateOperationData">
<input message="tns:UpdateOperationDataRequest"/>
<output message="tns:UpdateOperationDataResponse"/>
<fault name="AuthorizationFault" message="tns:AuthorizationFault"/>
<fault name="OperationHistoryFault" message="tns:OperationHistoryFault"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="WebOperationHistory" type="tns:OperationHistoryInterface">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="GetOperationHistory">
<soap:operation style="document"/>
<input>
<soap:header message="tns:getOperationHistoryIn" part="AuthorizationHeader" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal" parts="historyRequest"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="AuthorizationFault">
<soap:fault name="AuthorizationFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
<fault name="OperationHistoryFault">
<soap:fault name="OperationHistoryFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="UpdateOperationData">
<soap:operation style="document"/>
<input>
<soap:header message="tns:UpdateOperationDataRequest" part="AuthorizationHeader" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal" parts="UpdateRequest"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="AuthorizationFault">
<soap:fault name="AuthorizationFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
<fault name="OperationHistoryFault">
<soap:fault name="OperationHistoryFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="OperationHistory">
<port name="OperationHistory" binding="tns:WebOperationHistory">
<soap:address location="http://vpdks1.russianpost.ru:8080/niips-operationhistory-web/OperationHistory"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

как на этот адрес отправить этот XML через SOAP?

C SOAP не работал просто никогда, тут задача возникла нужно достучаться по этому протоколу на некий URL и получать оттуда данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно еще в хиадере слать:

SOAPAction: tns:getOperationHistoryIn

ну и отправлять post'om

ну и правильную xml слать. с `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` и т.д

Comment: @shurik стукни в скайп, пообщаться.

Я уже запарился в нете искать всякую хрень с одним и тем же примером.

Да, хидеры нужно слать.

Comment: А в ответ тишина :)

Comment: Добавил в список.

Разобрался с SOAP.